# To excel formats

Tags: python, excel, pandas, export-to-excel

I want to export a pandas dataframe to Excel, but I face several issue:

1/ I have a column beginning with "=", which of course is read like a formula with excel.
To avoid that, for my datframe column I did that:

```
df['mc'] = "'" + df['mc']
```

But when I do that Excel read it as a text and don't delete the "'" as it should do...

For example:

```
d = p.DataFrame({'test1': ["=1+2+3"], 'test2': ["'=1+2+3"]})
d.to_excel('test3.xlsx')
```

First column is written "6". Second is written "'=1+2+3"
What I want is "=1+2+3"

2/ My text columns are French ones with special character like "oe" (like in oeuf = egg, called "le e dans l'o"), which are not exported...
I encoded the export like this:

```
df.to_excel("test1.xlsx", encoding='utf8')
```

But it doesn't change anything. Do you know how I should do it?
Thanks,

Comment: You could `.apply(lambda x: "'"+x if x[0] == "=" else x)` to only apply to strings with equals...

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
df.to_excel("test1.xlsx",encoding='utf-8-sig')
```